# Waiting for code to finish with Ionic lifecycles

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I have code in my ionViewWillLoad() function:

```
ionViewWillLoad() {
  if (this.city) {
    this.apiService.getProductsByCategory(this.city.CategoryID)
      .subscribe((data: Product[]) => {
          this.extractActivities(data) 
        }, 
        (err) => console.log(err),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

And code in ionViewDidEnter() function:

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.activities.length; i++) {
    $('.' + this.activities[i].name.replace(/\s/g, '')).slick({
      speed: 300,
      slidesToShow: 2,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      prevArrow: $('.r-arrow' + i),
      nextArrow: $('.l-arrow' + i),
    })
  }
}
```

ionViewDidEnter code is dependable on ionViewWillLoad code. How do I run 'DidEnter' only after 'WillLoad' is finished?

Answer (score 1):

If the code doesn't need to run every time the page is entered you could just run the code of your didEnter method right after

```
this.extractActivities(data)
// perform action here
```

Otherwise you could either use the ionic lifecycle hook ionViewDidLoad or angular lifecycle hook ngAfterViewInit. If you need to do it inside ionViewDidEnter just add a boolean instance variable to your page that indicates wether the ionViewWillLoad Method completed. Set it to true after the load is finished.

```
this.extractActivities(data)
// perform action here
this.loadComplete = true;
```

and in your

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
  if(!this.loadComplete){
    return;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < this.activities.length; i++) {
    $('.' + this.activities[i].name.replace(/\s/g, '')).slick({
      speed: 300,
      slidesToShow: 2,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      prevArrow: $('.r-arrow' + i),
      nextArrow: $('.l-arrow' + i),
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: This still doesn't work, ionViewDidEnter function must run. Now it checks once and won't run again